# Kafka Sink to Data Lake Storage without Confluent

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to find options for Open Source Kafka writing directly to Azure Data Lake storage Gen2 . It seems I have few options and mostly circling around Confluent like below :

1. Use Confluent Cloud with Apache Kafka - Need to Subscribe with Confluent and pay charges ([Confluent Cloud with ADLS](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-azure-datalakeGen2-storage-sink.html)
2. Use Azure VM with Confluent Hub and Install Confluent Platform

At present I am not wiling to pay Confluent licensing and not want to test with confluent package (more and more wrappers and hoops around)

Any option to use Open source Kafka directly to write data to ADLS Gen2 ? If yes how can we achieve this any useful information to share ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Kafka Connect is Apache2 licensed product and an open-platform consisting of plugins; Confluent Platform/Cloud is not a requirement to use it. [You can download the Azure connector as a ZIP file](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-data-lake-gen2-storage) and install it [like any other](https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/userguide.html#connect-installing-plugins)

**However**, it is at Confluent's (or any developer) discretion to provide a paid [license agreement for their software and any support, and there might otherwise be a limited trial period where you can use the plugin for some time](https://www.confluent.io/software-evaluation-license/).

That being said, you do not "need" Confluent Platform, and there are no "hoops" to using it if you did because it only adds *extras* to Apache Kafka+Zookeeper, it is not its own thing (you can use your existing Kafka installation with the other Confluent products)

Regarding other open-source things. StackOverflow is not the place for software recommendations or seeking tools/libraries. You can use Spark/Flink/Nifi, though, I'm sure to reimplement a similar pipeline as Kafka Connect, or you can write your own Kafka Connector based on the open-source [`kafka-connect-storage-cloud`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud) project that is used as a base for S3, GCS, and Azure, AFAIK.

Comment: that clarifies great . thank you but looks like the zip also supplied from confluence where the confusion lies so I assume its just open to use by anybody w/o licensing . Also I am looking for the usage of this connector and how from a raw Kafka cluster setup perspective . is there any pointers ?

Comment: 1) Confluence is an Atlassian product, and has nothing to do with Kafka 2) The ZIP includes compiled code. At runtime, the code **does** perform a license check, although you get an evaluation period to use it, as per the Confluent License linked 3) As answered, put the code in `plugin.path` folder mentioned in  your Kafka Connect property file, then start the server and that plugin would be available for use

Comment: Sure. I will try it out . So per my understanding there is nothing available w/o licensing (via confluence or confluence like) to get Kafka Open source unlicensed direct connector to connect ADLS object storage ? Also do you have usage details of this zip package and corresponding documentation to use if that is the only option ?

Comment: Again, Confluence is a wiki software has nothing to do with Kafka. And you already got another answer about Apache Camel, which you will also need to setup in the `plugin.path`

Answer (score 0):

There is Apache Camel Connectors, which has an Azure Datalake connector for sending and receiving data. (sink and source) Check this out: https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/connectors/camel-azure-storage-datalake-kafka-sink-connector.html
This is a free solution that doesnt require Confluent licenses or technologies to be used.

Comment: Just an FYI--you dont need a license to use Camel Kafka Connector to directly connect.